# How to evaluate permutation tests in vegan when strata are are not balanced

Tags: r, permutation-test, nested-models, vegan

I have a multivariate data set of 12 sites, and 4 plots per site, **except one site which only has three plots.**
There two variables of interest:  `site_type`, which is a property of a site, and ChaussB, which is a property of a plot.

```
genedat <- structure(list(
  site_type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CTRL", "OSP", "PMI", "SPS"), class = "factor"), 
  site_num = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L,  9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"), 
  class = "factor"), 
  ChaussB = c(7.425, 5.835,   5.777, 3.816, 8.284, 4.148, 0.712, 12.234, 6.558, 8.685, 5.304,  25.443, 6.022, 10.605, 17.453, 12.681, 4.381, 10.641, 8.478,  1.937, 5.504, 8.848, 1.445, 13, 7.379, 7.542, 13.942, 15.505,  13.876, 17.58, 7.322, 6.749, 5.007, 2.04, 5.063, 3.077, 9.61,  4.68, 8.991, 5.799, 2.798, 1.702, 0.683, 19, 8.39, 8.019, 9.706), 
  Z1 = c(285.461, 207.466, 161.13, 162.624, 270.471, 107.079, 50.522, 164.952, 99.938, 181.951, 244.077, 157.943, 124.334,  201.943, 182.312, 171.339, 370.793, 145.31, 244.258, 218.455,  145.447, 270.552, 381.829, 315.364, 318.925, 159.2, 255.79, 141.412,  136.567, 109.169, 127.212, 305.645, 277.233, 140.165, 264.726, 119.308, 200.399, 106.124, 219.879, 252.846, 239.107, 266.249, 272.691, 245.463, 176.893, 251.416, 228.163), 
  Z2 = c(76.481, 82.479, 59.776, 44.439, 43.108, 53.851, 87.029, 92.685, 98.246, 78.143, 70.159, 57.39, 82.761, 91.517, 80.155, 36.963, 79.341,  53.117, 77.068, 115.471, 78.491, 98.71, 69.541, 70.084, 48.926, 89.344, 64.351, 73.147, 44.431, 54.798, 77.864, 70.944, 83.23,  79.195, 81.495, 138.205, 112.615, 87.538, 81.669, 108.527, 78.925,  114.899, 61.416, 143.321, 117.269, 111.583, 55.279), 
  pbsk3 = c(6.663, 17.307, 11.469, 12.851, 36.823, 46.956, 28.913, 55.045, 39.419,  58.338, 65.385, 97.297, 73.005, 11.543, 53.013, 40.485, 8.473, 49.538, 38.215, 27.183, 14.693, 28.688, 17.71, 9.976, 14.466,  4.395, 8.764, 116.219, 82.718, 85.201, 97.431, 8.263, 9.168,   6.056, 4.617, 60.954, 81.366, 72.638, 70.809, 4.872, 3.448, 0.896,  2.547, 4.572, 13.88, 10.459, 14.79), 
  ef = c(74.583, 56.687, 52.155, 43.926, 52.836, 80.689, 79.235, 64.175, 63.455, 82.463, 83.243,  73.91, 66.312, 45.503, 71.731, 62.278, 64.739, 67.313, 89.245,  54.963, 43.247, 89.854, 50.678, 51.555, 73.532, 56.55, 58.86, 67.018, 71.244, 88.623, 74.962, 46.056, 69.064, 60.321, 72.253,  67.595, 73.161, 78.051, 63.705, 68.714, 82.995, 67.746, 44.37,  74.057, 60.539, 31.707, 51.561), 
  Neith = c(7.535, 3.927, 3.647,  1.696, 8.863, 16.422, 11.33, 16.493, 18.186, 8.475, 16.635, 22.312, 5.624, 17.778, 20.342, 0.271, 1.711, 1.075, 0, 9.429, 0.306, 0.286, 1.332, 14.866, 0.093, 0.929, 4.241, 10.617, 12.96, 7.924, 7.466, 1.762, 1.709, 1.307, 1.02, 2.623, 14.468, 14.437, 13.101, 3.515, 1.818, 3.455, 9.414, 4.92, 7.361, 9.355, 1.543), 
  msoA = c(0.208,  0.149, 0, 0, 0, 3.201, 17.085, 0, 12.879, 0.301, 0, 7.179, 15.91,  0.596, 1.393, 1.383, 0, 10.909, 0.979, 21.244, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.092,  0.251, 0.139, 0.54, 2.932, 12.859, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.368, 1.024, 5.467, 7.206, 0.319, 0.272, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
  Drm = c(26.657,  16.632, 26.695, 12.823, 15.28, 16.241, 15.313, 21.858, 10.588,  22.686, 25.015, 70.114, 14.031, 37.692, 31.842, 14.353, 21.307,   16.575, 19.949, 21.706, 11.353, 9.786, 12.777, 19.257, 25.263,   11.198, 29.731, 38.233, 31.191, 31.724, 20.978, 12.031, 27.106, 13.521, 19.873, 22.596, 20.086, 23.748, 22.056, 10.99, 25.798, 24.667, 26.718, 18.299, 25.383, 15.376, 15.916), 
  Whal = c(7.571,  12.275, 5.446, 3.262, 29.145, 53.783, 22.482, 71.746, 44.422,   58.025, 47.542, 119.587, 24.33, 16.454, 77.451, 6.668, 11.578, 4.374, 11.752, 39.356, 19.197, 12.151, 3.35, 15.546, 7.742, 5.725,  18.717, 36.162, 41.111, 25.293, 22.038, 2.088, 6.439, 7.574,  5.54, 39.086, 45.556, 49.419, 33.35, 3.715, 10.993, 3.706, 6.926,  12.557, 18.441, 4.13, 7.415), 
  Nock = c(7.751, 7.863, 17.935,  7.088, 7.134, 11.764, 8.457, 20.806, 15.75, 16.481, 10.3, 31.506,  8.831, 8.393, 12.915, 6.11, 5.004, 11.309, 11.001, 7.87, 1.562,  3.002, 0, 10.946, 10.122, 3.002, 3.433, 24.9, 14.014, 18.458,  17.227, 7.945, 7.428, 4.377, 7.417, 9.363, 16.04, 10.143, 5.904,  7.983, 4.357, 6.156, 11.373, 5.216, 12.634, 7.536, 6.739), 
  dNor = c(0,  1.479, 0.268, 0, 1.807, 6.288, 0.729, 6.799, 1.448, 4.553, 5.276,   13.856, 1.799, 0, 1.271, 0, 0.344, 0, 0, 1.957, 0, 0.991, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.281, 1.937, 1.699, 2.541, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.307, 7.611, 1.847, 2.125, 0, 0, 2.013, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.513), 
  rNor = c(12.375,  10.044, 6.229, 4.069, 13.416, 26.31, 28.969, 39.706, 17.511, 14.154, 21.506, 44.089, 12.276, 22.153, 36.964, 1.737, 1.615, 2.287, 0, 27.207, 1.881, 1.516, 1.272, 13.883, 0.866, 1.801,  5.971, 11.734, 13.156, 9.034, 8.395, 3.812, 2.792, 4.706, 1.59,  20.828, 14.984, 14.384, 18.532, 5.065, 2.486, 9.731, 10.364,  5.855, 15.134, 8.966, 7.05)), row.names = c(NA, -47L), class = "data.frame")
```

We can ordinate these data to see how they disperse by `site_type`:

```
library(vegan)
set.seed(14)
genNMDS <- metaMDS(genedat[,4:14], try=20, trymax=1000, k=2, maxit=200)
```

[image: ordination of 47 points colored by site_type and with convex hull by site_type]

If we were do to any sort of permutation test on this, there would be an issue of pseudoreplication, because the sample size (n=47 plots) is inappropriate here because `site_type` is a property of site (n=12).

```
> envfit(genNMDS ~ site_type, data=genedat)

***FACTORS:

Centroids:
                NMDS1   NMDS2
site_typeCTRL -0.1382 -0.0674
site_typeOSP  -0.0227 -0.0366
site_typePMI   0.0761  0.0574
site_typeSPS   0.0910  0.0514

Goodness of fit:
              r2 Pr(>r)   
site_type 0.2294  0.009 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999


> adonis(genedat[,4:14] ~ site_type, data=genedat)

Call:
adonis(formula = genedat[, 4:14] ~ site_type, data = genedat) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

          Df SumsOfSqs  MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)   
site_type  3   0.33944 0.113148  3.8859 0.21329  0.003 **
Residuals 43   1.25205 0.029117         0.78671          
Total     46   1.59149                  1.00000          
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

We should really be considering sites as strata, and permuting entire sites, using the `how()` function in the `permute` package.

```
plot(genNMDS, type = "n")
points(genNMDS, display = "sites", col = colvec[genedat$site_type], pch=19)
ordihull(genNMDS, groups=genedat$site_num, col= colvec[c(2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1)], draw="polygon") 
library(permute)
h=with(genedat, how(within=Within(type="free"), plots=Plots(strata=site_num, type="free")))
```

[image: ordination of 47 data points, colored by site_type and convex hulls by site number]

But if we do so, as discussed in the `permute::how()` documentation and [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230731/how-to-use-the-how-function-for-an-unbalanced-repeated-design/60243307#60243307) we run into an error because we are missing a plot for one of the sites.

```
> envfit(genNMDS ~ site_type, data=genedat, perm=h)
Error in check(sn, control = control, quietly = quietly) : 
  Design must be balanced if permuting 'strata'.
> adonis(genedat[,4:14] ~ site_type, data=genedat, perm=h)
Error in check(sn, control = control, quietly = quietly) : 
  Design must be balanced if permuting 'strata'.
```

**Question 1:  Why must the design be balanced?**  I suspect it must have something to do with the number of possible ways you can permute a 4-plot site into a 3-plot site, and therefore each `site_type` group has a slightly different power associated with it. But I would appreciate a more extensive explanation.

**Question 2:  How can I assess the question of whether the site_types are significantly separating on either the ordination (`envfit`) or in the distance matrix (`adonis`) given the imbalance that precludes permuting by strata?**

One solution I came up with is the average all plot data by site, and then evaluate on a data set of n=12 (without the subsampling).

```
library(dplyr)
genedatagg <- genedat %>% group_by(site_num, site_type) %>% summarize(across(is.numeric, mean))
set.seed(14)
aggNMDS <- metaMDS(genedatagg[,4:14], try=20, trymax=1000, k=2, maxit=200)
plot(aggNMDS, type = "n")
points(aggNMDS, display = "sites", col = colvec[genedatagg$site_type], pch=19)
ordihull(aggNMDS, groups=genedatagg$site_type,draw="polygon", col=colvec)
```

[image: ordination of the 12 aggregated sites with convex hull by site_type]

```
> envfit(aggNMDS ~ site_type, data=genedatagg)

***FACTORS:

Centroids:
                NMDS1   NMDS2
site_typeCTRL -0.1790  0.0570
site_typeOSP  -0.0530  0.0283
site_typePMI   0.1426 -0.0394
site_typeSPS   0.0894 -0.0459

Goodness of fit:
              r2 Pr(>r)
site_type 0.4593  0.143
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

> adonis(genedatagg[,4:14] ~ site_type, data=genedatagg)

Call:
adonis(formula = genedatagg[, 4:14] ~ site_type, data = genedatagg) 

Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Terms added sequentially (first to last)

          Df SumsOfSqs  MeanSqs F.Model      R2 Pr(>F)
site_type  3   0.08214 0.027380  1.4614 0.35402  0.267
Residuals  8   0.14988 0.018735         0.64598       
Total     11   0.23202                  1.00000
```

But this is not optimal if I simultaneously want to test ChaussB as this variable is a property of a plot, not a site (we would lose power for this variable by aggregating).

```
envfit(aggNMDS ~ site_type + ChaussB, data=genedatagg)
adonis(genedatagg[,4:14] ~ site_type + ChaussB, data=genedatagg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: The design must be balanced because you're trying to swap groups of samples with one another such that all the samples that were in group A are swamped with all the samples from group B and you can only do that if you have groups of the same size. If you have groups of different size, the changes you would be making to the data wouldn't be purely testing a variable that varied at the strata level; whenever you swapped a 3-sample group with a 4-sample group the extra sample would get left around somewhere and thus the ordering within groups would also be affected.

It's important to note that when permuting strata like this, it is different to simply permuting the strata variable at random. The strata impose internal structure and we must keep that structure the same (i.e. the same internal ordering).

Q2: Drop one of the samples from each of the sites with only 4 plots, or drop the site with only 3 plots. Either way that would make the data set balanced. You would only need to do this for the specific test of variation at the site level; you could keep all the data for the test for things that vary at the plot level because you can permute within the levels of the strata without having equally sized groups.